# Service: onCreate called again after restarting app

Tags: android, service

I pass through the data to be processed via intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationService.class);
intent.putExtra....
...
startService(intent);
```

onCreate method called once while browsing app, but when I closed app and removed from task list(I checked, service is still runing), then I start app again - Service onCreate called again.

From the doc:

> If the service is not already running, the system first calls
>   onCreate(), then calls onStartCommand().

**Update:**

> What constant are you returning at the end of your onStartCommand
>   method?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

> Pleasee post the type of service and startmode

```
LocationService extends Service
```

Comment: What constant are you returning at the end of your `onStartCommand` method?

Comment: Pleasee post the type of service and startmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the android doc is correct , it will call the service's onCreate() only first time it is created , and then delivers all the intents to onStartCommand() .

But I've have came across these two google groups having the discussion that might be helpful to you

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/LtmA9xbrD5A
and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/H-DSQ4-tiac

Not much of a help , but might be of some interest .

Enjoy !